# Prevent mySql from changing specific rows

Tags: mysql, synchronization

I'm using mysqldumb command to export/import a database (syncing between two machines). It works well, but I have a couple of rows that I don't want to be changed when importing the dumbed mysql file.

I know I can change the rows after restoring the file, but I wanted to know if a solution to prevent (a user) from changing some rows is possible.

Comment: I *highly* doubt it, but if you're right that would be awesome.

Comment: BTW it is mysqldump, not mysqldumb ;-)

Comment: Thank you, that was silly from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an after trigger that resets the data back to its original state if it matches certain criteria.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you can identify those rows unequivocally. You could write a simple script that removes those lines and executes mysqldump; for example, if you use Linux:

```
cat filename.txt | grep -v "line you want to exclude" > newfile_without_the_line_u_want_to_exclude.txt
```

If it's always the same line number you could use sed, etc.